# How to save multiple values to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

So I would like to know how to save and check different values in a file. I have tried to read a file

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    varName = f.readline()
```

and this to write things to a file however this overwrites anything already in the file

```
with open('topname.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(name))
    f.close()
```

another problem is when I want to check the values by using a for loop however that didn't work. I was wondering if there was any other way to check, read and write values to/from a file.

An example of this is a login page where people can make accounts and log in and the program checks if the username and password exist.

When I looked on the internet it talked about a thing called pickle but it wasn't the same thing as what I wanted from what I could see.

Comment: try this:  `with open('topname.txt', 'w+') as f`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)?

Comment: @balderman Does this do the same as a+?

Comment: @PeterWood No I haven't. Would it be useful if I did?

Comment: @luckyjd I expect it would be useful, why not [try and see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)?

Comment: @PeterWood Fair enough, I guess I will, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you need to open the file in append mode:

```
with open('topname.txt', 'a+') as f:
     f.write(str(name))
     f.close()
```

The '+' sign in append mode indicates that the script will create a new file if it doesn't already exist, if it does, it'll just append to it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to "append" to the file, so open it with mode `'a'` instead of `'w'`.

Also, do not call `f.close()` inside of the `with` block.  `with` will close the file for you after the block.

```
with open('topname.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(name))
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thank you, this will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

To append data to an existing file use `open("Filename", "a")` for "append mode." This is in contrast to your "read" and "write" modes.

Comment: Thank you, this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read ,write and update, you need to open file `file = open('topname.txt', 'a+')` and to check every line to match user data `for line in file:print(line)` .Other operations like `file.read(), file.write()` will help. Remember to release resources by closing file finally `file.close()`